# Ansible - connect to postgres without password

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I'm trying to create a user on Postgres with ansible, but I have no password defined on user Postgres DB.

```
name: Connect to postgres database, create toto user, and grant access SUPERUSER, INHERIT When PGversion > 10
postgresql_user:
    login_host: 127.0.0.1
    db: postgres
    name: toto
    password: "{{toto}}"
    role_attr_flags: SUPERUSER,INHERIT
    login_user: postgres
    login_password: "toto" 
    port: "{{port_postgres}}"
```

When I launch without a password, I have this error message in my playbook.

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

If I put a password "toto" to the user on Postgres and in my playbook, it's ok!

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use passwordless psql from `sudo -u postgres`, which is translates to Ansible's:

```
- name: Add user
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
  postgresql_user:
    db: postgres
    name: ...
```